# Can I develop Cross-Platform Desktop Applications using Visual C++?

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, cross-platform

I'd like to develop a cross platform desktop application 
I found on google that I can do that using QT
but I'm more interested in Visual Studio (c++)
so can I develop cross platform applications using visual c++ ?

Comment: yes you can, but you'd develop a cross-platform ui framework first.

Comment: Visual Studio is an IDE, Qt an UI toolkit. That's orthogonal, you can develop Qt applications in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio is an IDE, and you can use several frameworks to build desktop applications in C++ using Visual Studio. If you choose a Windows-specific framework, for example MFC, then your application will be Windows-only, of course.

But, at the same time, if you pick a *cross-platform* framework, like Qt, you can develop cross-platform desktop applications using Visual Studio in C++.

While Qt has its own IDE (Qt Creator), a [Qt Visual Studio add-in](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-support.html) is also available:

> The Qt Visual Studio Add-in allows programmers to create, build, debug
>   and run Qt applications from within non-Express versions of Microsoft
>   Visual Studio 2008, 2010, and 2012. The add-in contains project
>   wizards, Qt project import/export support, integrated Qt resource
>   manager and automated build setup for the Qt Meta-Object Compiler,
>   User Interface Compiler, and Resource Compiler.